# A word or an idiom for not wanting to look into something else to not get sidetracked

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests

Example:

> In this article about bugs I focus primarily on 7-legged bugs and
> purposely not consider spiders as it would require me to [***look into
> and explain the details I don't want to here***] them which is not the
> point here.

In a way, it's close to **to dirty one's hands with smh** but without a negative connotation.

I'm quite confident there's a word for it, but I just can't remember it. I think **to dip into** is close, but too casual (slang-ish), I'm looking for something for more formal writing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"To look into something else" and "get sidetracked" is *to fall down a rabbit hole*.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rabbit%20hole) calls a *rabbit hole*

> a...situation...in which the pursuit of something (such as an answer
> or solution) leads to other questions, problems, or pursuits

Answer (score 1):

You don’t want to be *distracted*:

> dis·tract  (dĭ-străkt)

tr.v. dis·tract·ed, dis·tract·ing, dis·tracts

1. To cause (someone) to have difficulty paying attention to something: The voices in the other room distracted him, so he couldn't concentrate on his homework.
2. To attract (the attention) away from its original focus; divert.
3. To cause to feel worried or uneasy; unsettle: The company's workforce was distracted by the prospect of a takeover.

The second definition is the most pertinent, as it notes that you want to keep the focus on the current topic.

From American Heritage Dictionary.
https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=distract

Comment: It’s worth noting, with general comments frozen, that the OP has not provided a sentence in which to use this word or phrase.

Answer (score 1):

It is common to use the phrase “beyond the scope” when describing the content of a paper and also setting out the limits of your discussion. See this discussion on Academia Stack Exchange: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/143708/beyond-the-scope-of-this-paper-phrase

So, I would reword your example sentence as follows:

In this article about bugs, I focus primarily on 7-legged bugs. Spiders are beyond the scope of this article.

(Just curious: What 7-legged bugs???)

Answer (score 0):

- I don't want to **bother about/bother my head with** this subject [for the time being/here/now].
- I will not **bother about/bother my head with** that in this presentation.

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/bother_1?q=bother)) **not bother yourself/your head with/about something**
> ​(especially British English) to not spend time/effort on something, because it is not important or you are not interested in it

This term is not informal but belongs to a neutral register.

The synonym "to trouble sb with sth" belongs also to a neutral register.

- I will not **trouble myself with** that now.

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/trouble_2)) **trouble somebody with something**
> I don't want to trouble the doctor with such a small problem.

Answer (score 0):

***delve into***:

> to examine something carefully in order to discover more information about someone or something:
>
> - It's not always a good idea ***to delve too deeply into*** someone's past. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/delve-into-sth))

***Delve*** is used here metaphorically. It literally means:

> reach inside a receptacle and search for something. ([OxfordL](https://www.google.com/search?q=delve%20meaning&sxsrf=ALeKk01q6hDlixOMUzlWeLQD8e3vaOva5A%3A1627626652082&ei=nJwDYamtBOXlxgPaja-YBw&oq=delve%20mean&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYADIMCAAQsQMQQxBGEPkBMgUIABCRAjIECAAQQzIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgQIABBDMgUIABCABDIECAAQQzIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEOgQIIxAnOgsIABCABBCxAxCDAToOCC4QgAQQsQMQxwEQowI6CAgAEIAEELEDOggILhCxAxCDAToLCC4QgAQQxwEQowI6BwgAELEDEAo6CwguEIAEEMcBEK8BOgcIABCxAxBDOgQILhBDOgUILhCABDoKCAAQgAQQhwIQFEoECEEYAFCouw9Yj8kPYJjXD2gAcAJ4AIABzgOIAYYUkgEJMC42LjMuMC4ymAEAoAEBwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz))

Here are examples of metaphorical use provided by [Freedictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/delve+into):

> - Because I was eager to ***delve into*** that novel further, I decided to write about it for my term paper.
> - I am just now ***delving into*** a study of the Trojan War.

And some formal contexts:

> - ... researchers in technology assisted in making sense of the collected artifacts as we ***delved deeper into*** the technical aspects of the technical agents. (*[Beyond Interpretivism? New Encounters with Technology and Organization](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=nDuIDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA78&dq=%22delved%20deeper%20into%20the%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiBr8POmIryAhVpVRUIHcvPBvg4ChDoATAEegQIBBAC)*, Lucas Introna, ‎Donncha Kavanagh, ‎Séamas Kelly)
> - The first incarnation of the ASU internship assessment effort ***did not delve into*** these subsidiary areas, but focused instead on central questions... ([*Assessing Media Education: A Resource Handbook for Educators and Administrators*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=d1UaraoHVPIC&pg=PA487&dq=%22delve%20into%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj2yLm1mYryAhXhVhUIHUGrD3o4ChDoATAHegQIAxAC), William G. Christ)

Your sentence would then be

> In this article about bugs I focus primarily on 7-legged bugs and
> purposely not consider spiders as it would require me *to delve into
> details about them* which is not the point here.